# Always click on the first link on Google Search Using Selenium In Python

Tags: python, selenium

I would like always click on the first link on Google using selenium robot for python.
So for example if I write this :

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("Tennis")
```

I would like to click on the first link that appears on Google

Thank you for your help !!

Comment: It doesn't work for me sorry

Comment: Goodluck handling the day google decides your test machine is a bot and asks you to manually re-verify with captchas...half way through your testcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted solution didn't work for me. So for anyone else that comes across that question `driver.find_element_by_tag_name("cite").click()` using python3 worked for me. However if you just want the link to the top search result it would be faster to use the requests and BeautifulSoup libraries as shown below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=something'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.find('cite').text)
```

Answer (score 2):

The xpath which is working as of Aug 2019 is

```
(//h3)[1]/../../a
```

i.e. find the first `h3` tag, move to its parents and find the first `a`.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//h3)[1]/../../a').click()
```

Google will surely change something in the future and then another approach will be needed.

**Old answer**

The results links all (used to have) have `h3` as the parent element, you can use that

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//h3)[1]/a').click()
```

Comment: Thank you it's working for me !!

Comment: And do you know how can I find all the link that contain a pdf file ?

Comment: That's a separate topic. @Bilkokuya is absolutely right with his comment, the approach will break if google changes something or if they recognize you are using a Selenium script. There are different, more stable approaches.
For finding PDF, inspect the PDF `span` in your browser and build the xpath from that.